# Batch Script and Exit

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have a main batch script that calls out to some sub batch scripts, which end with the `EXIT` keyword.  This, in turn, let me out to the command prompt again. Is there any way to capture the `EXIT` in the main script and then just run the next line?

Thx

Comment: Just remove the EXIT from those sub-batch scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `call` when you call another script.

```
...
call someother.cmd
...
```